# What's the proper way to handle mongoose connections with express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a very simple "server.js" setup that I am trying to run:

```
var express = require('express'),
    wines = require('./routes/testscripts');

var app = express();

app.get('/first_test', wines.popSingleData);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

This is set up to connect to `localhost:3000`

When I navigate to `localhost:3000/first_test`, it calls the "popSingleData" method within testscript.js:

```
...
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    var db = mongoose.connection;

    console.log('include called');

exports.popSingleData = function(req, res) {

//  var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

//  var db = mongoose.connection;

    console.log('function called');

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    console.log('error handler set');
    db.once('open', function callback () {
        //yay!
        console.log("DB Opened");

        var someSchema = require('../models/someSchema');

        someSchema.find(function (err, found){
            if (err) 
            {
                console.log('err');
            }

            if(found.length != 0) 
            {
                console.log("Found Data:");
                console.log(found);
                for( var i = 0; i < found.length; i++)
                {
                    res.jsonp((found[i]));
                }
            }
        });


    });

};
...
```

The lines that are causing issue are the first 3:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

When they are declared within the function, the script runs as expected, printing out JSON objects it found from the database. When they are defined within testscript.js, but *outside the scope of the method*, the program hangs on the `db.once('open', function callback () {...}); command`.

Could someone shed some light on the difference that occurs from moving these 3 lines of code? Do I really need to make a new connection every time I want a different function to access the database?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you connected to the database already, the `once` event won't fire again. The database was already connected for the entire NodeJs process when it was globally connected (outside of the function).

The call to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');` makes the connection and opens it.

So, instead of opening it on each function call (which would be an inefficient way to interact with MongoDB) `connect` right away when the NodeJs app is started, and consider that there will be a period where the connection may not be available (as it's async), or don't start the app (`listen`) until the connection is complete (or with a timeout). With Mongoose, until the connection is made, all commands are buffered (but that may not be the behavior you want). You can use the `open` event if you want to know when the connection is complete.

The connection is found here: `mongoose.connection` if you use the `connect` function to create the connection.

Once the connection is opened, you can use it from your `popSingleData` function without using the `once` event and callback. There's a connection pool automatically maintained.

For more about connections, read [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html).

Comment: So `mongoose.connect` is what creates the connection? So the reason it doesn't function when outside the method, is that the method is finding it already open, so the db.once("open") never happens?

Comment: Wonderful. Moved the code out of the callback and it appears to be working great. Thanks very much!

Comment: How to pass a connection to routes in Expressjs app? Routes are in separate modules, folders.

Comment: @Green - just centralize the connection and fetch it in the routes. Or preinit the routes with the connection. I've done both.

Comment: an example callback when mongoose real connect the database?