# Nodejs variable declaration

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to Nodejs and javascript for that matter. I have started a project with use of express generator and have installed mongoose pacakge with it .

on the routes/index.js file I have this code

```
 var express = require('express');
 var router = express.Router();
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
 var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
 db.once('open', function (callback) {
    var toSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       state : Boolean
    });
    var listing = mongoose.model('todoSchema', toSchema)
 });

 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   var silence = new listing({ name: 'Silence', state:true })
   console.log(silence.name) // 'Silence'
   res.render('index', { title: silence.name });
 });
module.exports = router;
```

But when I start the server I get error saying

```
listing is not defined

 ReferenceError: listing is not defined
at module.exports (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\routes\index.js:18:20)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
  D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at next (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
   at Route.dispatch (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:81:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
at D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:235:24
at Function.proto.process_params (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:313:12)
at D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:229:12
at Function.match_layer (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:296:3)
at next (D:\xampp\htdocs\nodeproject\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:190:10)
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong  and how a variable declaration works ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259725/whats-the-proper-way-to-handle-mongoose-connections-with-express-js

Answer (score 2):

That's because your listing variable was defined out of the [scope](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) you want to use it. Try to declare the variable outside the callback function:

```
var listing;
 db.once('open', function (callback) {
    var toSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       state : Boolean
    });
    listing = mongoose.model('todoSchema', toSchema);
 });

 // you can use it anywhere as soon as it is initialized in time.
```

Answer (score 0):

The confusion is coming from the fact that JavaScript does not have block scope, but it has function scope. You are defining `listing` in a function, therefore that variable will only exist in that function. Try defining your variable outside of the function scope:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var listing;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

 var db = mongoose.connection;
 db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
 db.once('open', function (callback) {
    var toSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       name: String,
       state : Boolean
    });
    listing = mongoose.model('todoSchema', toSchema)
 });

 /* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   var silence = new listing({ name: 'Silence', state:true })
   console.log(silence.name) // 'Silence'
   res.render('index', { title: silence.name });
 });
module.exports = router;
```